# Segmentation fault when creating a vector of pointers (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that implements Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I'm first working on reading in txt file data into a vector of pointer arrays so I can work with it. (the file contains # of vertices (7 in this case), vertices and their respective edges, and weight). See below:

```
7
2
2  2
4  1
2
4  3
5  10
2
1  4
6  5
4
3  2
5  2
6  8
7  4
1
7  6
0
1
6  1
```

In my Main.cpp I'm trying to create a vector of pointers to Vertex objects with the following line:

```
vector<Vertex*> vertices;
```

I'm then trying to populate the vector with the following code:

```
for(int i=1;i < numVertices; i++)
    {   
        file >> numEdges;
        cout << "At vertex " << i << " the number of edges is " << numEdges << endl;
        vertices[i] = new Vertex();
        //Vertex newVertex;

        //Using the i counter variable in the outer for loop to identify
        //the what vertex what are currently looking at in order to read in the correct adjacent vertex and weight
        cout << "LENGTH OF VERTICES[i]: " << vertices.size() << endl;
        vertices[i]->setVertexNum(i);
        //newVertex.setVertexNum(i);

        for(int j=1;j<=numEdges;j++)
        {
            file >> adjacentVertex;
            cout << "The adjacent vertex is: " << adjacentVertex << endl;


            file >> weight;
            cout << "The weight is: " <<  weight << endl;
            cout << endl;

            vertices[i]->setAdjacentVertex(adjacentVertex, weight);
        }
        //cout << "LENGTH OF VERTICES[i]: " << vertices.size() << endl;
        vertices.push_back(vertices[i]);
    }
```

However, I'm getting a seg fault and I can't understand why. I've declared pointer vectors like this before with no problem and I'm hoping someone on here might be able to point me in the correct direction.

It is interesting though because if I change the vector initialization to the following, I do not get a seg fault:

```
vector<Vertex*> vertices(numVertices + 1, NULL);
```

However, I do not want to preset the vector to a specific size, I just want it initialized.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you start your loops at 1?  Arrays in C++ are indexed starting from 0.

Comment: This is why we have debuggers. Sure, someone can post an answer for you, but how does that help you figure out how to solve your own problems? Have you tried a debugger yet?

Comment: On which line of code does the segfault happen?

Comment: @SanJacinto Already used a debugger and more often than not, the answers on here contain informative answers that not only help me, but also teach me why/where I went wrong. This is why I use StackOverflow, and I'm assuming the same is true for the majority of us.

Comment: Sure, then I guess you know the exact line the program crashes on and the cause of it. Perhaps then you can post your own answer and accept it. Hopefully it will be good enough to describe how you went about debugging it and new programmers will also learn how to use a debugger like every other programmer in the world.

Comment: @carbon_ghost - You need to tell us where `vertices` was initialized.  You are attempting to access `vertices[i]`, and no one knows if there is an `i` entry in the vector.  Also, you starting an index at 1 is a red flag.  Trying to mimic a 1-based array is error-prone.  You're practically begging for an off-by-1 error somewhere in your code when you do things like that.

Comment: @carbon_ghost Your question is too long and not precise enough. Generally speaking, when you have a bug that you don't understand, try to replicate the bug on the smallest possible example you can think of. Doing that, you'll isolate exactly what you don't understand, and you'll save everyone a lot of time spent trying to answer your question (and possibly downvotes as well).

Answer (score 3):

You've not provided enough information to definitively answer your problem, but I can point out a few obvious gotchas in your code.

"In my Main.cpp I'm trying to create a vector of pointers to Vertex objects with the following line:

```
vector<Vertex*> vertices;
```

We don't know whether the remaining code is in main or not, or if you are passing it, but a common mistake is to pass the vector by value rather than by reference. Passing by value copies the empty vector from main into a local function copy, populates that, and then discards it. The code returns to main where main's copy of vertices is untouched:

```
void wrong(vector<Vertex*> vertices) {
}

void right(vector<Vertex*>& vertices) {
}

vector<Vertex*> alternative() {
    vector<Vertex*> vertices;
    ...
    return vertices;
}
```

The next problem is your for loop, which starts at 1. In the C and C++ languages, arrays use "zero-based" offsets. That is, the first element in an array or vector is element 0:

```
char str[] = "hello";
std::cout << "str[0] = " << str[0] << "\n";
std::cout << "str[1] = " << str[1] << "\n";
```

will output

```
str[0] = h
str[1] = e
```

Your code is for some reason operating on a 1-base offset:

```
for(int i=1;i < numVertices; i++)
```

The next problem is that you immediately reference the element of the vector. C++'s `vector` class does not *automatically* grow the data when you do this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
int i = v[23]; // may crash; "undefined behavior".
```

Your code appears to do exactly this:

```
for(int i=1;i < numVertices; i++)
{   
    ...
    vertices[i] = new Vertex();
```

You need to ask the vector to make `i` elements available. You can do this two ways:

```
vertices.resize(numVertices);
```

This pre-sizes the vector in one go, and populates it with `numVertices` default-initialized values in one pop. Nice and efficient. Or you can do the following:

```
vertices.reserve(numVertices);
for ( ... ) {
    Vertex* newVert = new Vertex();
    vertices.push_back(newVert);
```

This tells the vector to prepare to be `numVertices` big, but doesn't actually increase 'size()', this avoids the vector having to move around memory as it grows.

But you could actually avoid all this new/delete hassle by using the vector properly:

```
vector<Vertex> vertices;
...
vertices.resize(numVertices);
```

At this point, you have `numVertices` default-initialized Vertex objects in an array, ready to be worked on. You can now just use:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i) {
    Vertex& vert = vertices[i]; // 'vert' is now a short-cut alias to vertices[i].
    vert.setVertNum(i);
}
```

Or you can use "emplace_back" if you are using C++11, which is a function that says "create a new vector element at the back, and here are it's constructor arguments":

```
class Vertex {
    size_t m_vertNum;
    float m_x, m_y;
public:
    Vertex(size_t vertNum, float x, float y)
        : m_vertNum(vertNum)
        , m_x
        , m_y
    {
    }
};

vector<Vertex> vertices;
size_t numVertices = 10;
vertices.reserve(numVertices);
for (size_t i = 0; i < numVertices; ++it) {
    vertices.emplace_back(/*vertNum*/ i, /*x*/ float(i * 3), /*y*/ float(i * 2));
    Vertex& vert = vertices.back();
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for using vectors of vertices, and for suggesting the `reserve` method.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer to a poor question.

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing this at the last line?

```
    vertices.push_back(vertices[i]);
```

You already have the vertex at vertices[i], why insert it at the last again? It will cause error because you have allocated memory for ith entry, but push_back will try to put again in (i+1)th entry, and that memory is not allocated. Segmentation fault means program is trying to access unauthorized memory.

also as others mentioned, starting loop for array, vector or similar containers should be from 0.

Edit

when you use

```
    vector<Vertex*> vertices(numVertices + 1, NULL);
```

then the problem does not occur because, vector has numVertices + 1 pointer to vetex items in it. when
i=numVertices, then in line

```
  vertices.push_back(vertices[i]);
```

the ith element is pushed in the (i+1)th location. But in previous case, there was no (i+1)th element when i =numVertices, hence the segment fault occurred since you tried to write in an unavailable memory location.

Comment: -1: Your edit is wrong, `std::vector<Vertex*> vertices(n+1,NULL);` does NOT "allocate memory for (n+1) items". See, this is the problem I'm talking about... I'll cancel my downvote if you edit your post no worries.

Comment: thanks @Sh3ljohn, I updated my answer. What I meant is reservation for numVertices+1 pointers, not actual items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is not an answer, but rather an important advice that could lead to an answer. I think I've repeated this so many times now, I should write a blog post about this.
WHY do you think you need a vector of pointers?

Vectors of pointers are very very rarely necessary, and they are difficult to manage, especially if you're a beginner in C++. Dijkstra's algorithm is not one of the cases where you'd need them. For some reason, I see beginners in C++ use the keyword `new` like in Java, they don't seem to understand that in C++, YOU are responsible for the memory management. This is very probably the source of your problem IMO.

My advice: try implementing the exact same algorithm by replacing `std::vector<Vertex*>` by `std::vector<Vertex>`. Let's see, this might "solve" your segfault problem by making it disappear.